# WSO2 Identity Server - Cannot Configure Custom Catch-all Exception Page

Tags: error-handling, tomcat7, wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0

For things such as a 500 errors and anything unforeseen, I'd like to configure my Identity Server instance to have our own branded error page to hide the server technology for security reasons and also just allow the error a little confusion.

At any rate, this no help:        https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Error+Messages

I tried editing /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml and added the standard way to define an error page for exceptions:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/NiceError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and then placed NiceError.jsp in /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/

So when I make a 500 error reoccurr, things change, but I'm sent to the carbon management console login page.  If I decide to login, I get served up with an 405 error like so:

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> type Status report
>
> message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
>   Apache Tomcat/7.0.55

The URL looks like:  https://hostname:9443/NiceError.jsp?sessionDataKey=eabd6c25-7c79-40a9-af87-3cd80a68367e&loginStatus=true

That doesn't help.

How can this kind of thing be setup to work?  It can't be hard with the right information.  Right? :)

Answer (score 0):

The referred documentation page is to customize error **messages** for identity related errors as its name sounds. It is not to create custom error pages.

By the way if you need to create custom error page, which is applicable to all web applications in your server instance, you may need to add your error page to **web.xml** in `/repository/conf/tomcat/` directory. It defines default values for **all** web applications loaded into your instance of Tomcat. As each application get deployed, above file is processed, followed by the  `/WEB-INF/web.xml` deployment descriptor from your own applications.

Thanks